# Updating PHP file to server not reflecting its functionality in app

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, socket.io, ratchet

I am an iOS developer and also have some experience in PHP development as well. I got a project from other developer in which we have chat module that uses Socket programing with Ratchet(http://socketo.me/) for chatting purpose. We are using AWS Ubuntu instance for the backend.

When i execute this command "ps aux | grep php" on server than I can see a chat server php file that we are using for chatting purpose on a specific port number that port number we are also using in app for communication.

I want to add some more functionality so the main issue is that when I make any change in that chat server file and upload it to server in the same directory which is indicting in this command "ps aux | grep php", its not reflecting the changes in app while file is uploaded successfully. I also tried to restart server using "sudo service httpd restart" but didn't get any success.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your chat is probably running with a command like:

```
php bin/chat-server.php
```

So restarting httpd won't help.
You should restart the service that runs the actual chat server.

Comment: I tried above command & its giving below error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'React\Socket\ConnectionException' with message 'Could not bind to tcp://0.0.0.0:4280: Address already in use' in /var/www/html/app/ratchet/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php:29
Stack trace:
/var/www/html/app/ratchet/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/Server/IoServer.php(70): React\Socket\Server->listen(4280, '0.0.0.0')
#1 /var/www/html/app/ratchet/bin/chat_server.php(258): Ratchet\Server\IoServer::factory(Object(ChatServer), 4280)
  thrown in /var/www/html/app/ratchet/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php

Comment: The php command stops when you close your terminal. You probably have something like a screen running to keep the the command running. You should first close the current process and then start up a new server. To start up the new server you should use the same command as used to start the current process.
You could try using "screen -ls" to see if your script is using a screen